# When getPrincipal() return User object and when it return UserDetail object?

Tags: spring, spring-security

My application uses J2eePreauth authentication provider and here is the common code to retrieve MyUser object:

```
MyUser user = (MyUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

It works all the time until most recently I may be upgrade Spring security or sth now it gives me

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.myapp.domain.MyUser
```

And the class of `MyUser` is just implement interface `UserDetails`

It's very strange that the casting works all the time but regarding most recent update it fall apart.

So my question is when does `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` return a UserDetail object and when does it return `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

Comment: Perhaps a function of the version of Spring that you're using?  What version did you upgrade Spring Security from and to?  Major & minor release versions (i.e., non-patch) can/will change the API.  Spring should have migration guides available online for major release upgrades.

Comment: I don't think you are asking the right quesiton. The class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User implements UserDetails so they are one and of the same.

The principal is always the result of the UserDetailsService that returned the object. What does your UserDetailsService look like?

Comment: I am having the same issue after moving from spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.6 to 1.4.4. Spring security is 4.1.4 according to the dependency hierarchy in maven.

Answer (score 1):

It always return to one type: Object

```
Object object = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

And the return object is type of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`. If you use predefined User class of Spring Security then you can cast it to User type:

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (User)object;
```

However, if you define your custom User class then there is another approach to this:

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

This will work 100% of the time because built-in User class of Spring Security implement UserDetails class. (You can read Spring source code for deeper understanding)
Then find your active User Object by: 
// Assuming that your `Id` field is `Long`, define `UserRepository interface`

```
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<domain.User,Long> {
     domain.User findOneByUsername(String username);
}
```

then

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
myCustomApp.domain.User = userRepository.findOneByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
```

Comment: I understand the point, and it is OK, but my concern is: I will get my User just by name, and what if more than one user have the same name?

Comment: For security purpose, you have to use a unique field to identify user. Usually username or email or userId. If you want to use "name" to identify user then you have to rethink about your design principle.